# Is put option a good alternative to shorting HTB shares

Tags: stocks, options, shorting-securities

A lot of companies I'm interested in shorting have hard to borrow shares (HTB) I often miss the trade because I can't borrow the shares to short.

I don't know much about option trading but I know that  puts are similar to shorting where you can gain when the price moves down.

I do not want to hold anything overnight but would puts be a good alternative for intraday shorting a stock with hard to borrow shares?

Answer (score 1):

As a general statement, buying a put is a substitute  for shorting shares.  However, there  are a number of disadvantages, even more so with a hard to borrow stock.

An option has a 'participation rate' (my terminology) which is represented by its delta (negative for puts and positive for calls).   A very deep in-the-money put has a delta of -1.00 so it will participate about 1:1 for every dollar that the stock drops.

A put with a strike price near the stock's current price has a delta of approximately -.50 so initially, it will increase only 1/2 the amount that the stock drops.  The more the stock drops, the higher the put's delta will become (higher meaning heading toward -1.00 not becoming more positive).

As for hard to borrow stocks, other people will likely have the same idea as you.  If that occurs, it will make all of the options more expensive (increased implied volatility or IV).  Any news that settles the traders would likely  result in a decrease in implied volatility, causing your premium to disappear right in front of your eyes. And conversely, increased IV would help you. You can see what average IV has been over the past year at [IVolatility](https://www.ivolatility.com/home.j).  Free sign up.

The options of hard to borrow stocks tend to be illiquid (low open interest and low daily volume).  If so, that means a large bid/ask spread.  So if you have a 50 cent B/A spread and a 50 delta put, you'll need the stock to move almost $1 just to break even.

So while this is a viable idea, it's not without considerations, especially for short term intraday trades.